# Scheduling post using python- graphAPI on facebook

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to schedule a post using python-graph API for Facebook? I'm trying to code this in Python and I couldn't find any such parameter in put_object method in its documentation (https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)

Can you suggest me any other way to attach time with every post or a way where I can assign a post to a particular date and time on a calendar?